# Forward Bearer Token IdentityServer Web-API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3, bearer-token

I have a Web Application that needs to call a Web API, using a bearer token.
This service will need to call a common service on its own with the user credentials included.

So: Client --> API1 --> API2

Can somebody help me if it is possible to:
- or ask a for a new server to server token for API1 to API2 with the user claims included
- or re-use the received token for the server to server call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you host both apis, then you can just forward the access token.
It is rather difficult to create a new token with the user credentials from an access token.

The token can be validated on both APIs, and you have the user claims on both APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but if you are using IdentityServer4, you'll want to create an [extension grant](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html), and "refresh" or "delegate" your token on API1 to create a new token for API2.